# "Runes: Letters used for cutting" - Meaning of "used for"

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

I've read The Hobbit by J.R.R.Tolkien in Spanish but trying to answer a question about a possible typo in another StackExchange forum, I've found this text in its English original preamble

> Runes were old letters originally **used for** cutting or scratching on
>   wood, stone, or metal, and so were thin and angular. At the time of
>   this tale only the Dwarves made use of them, especially for private or
>   secret records.

I thought that in "use for", the verb **use** means

> to put something such as a tool, skill, or building to a particular purpose

So if we used a knife to cut the steak, that knife was **used for cutting**. But I don't get how a letter can be used for cutting or scratching.
I know that Tolkien was pointing that runes were carved on those surfaces using tools, something like

> Runes were old letters that originally **used to be cutted** or scratched on
>   wood, stone, etc.

but I haven't found evidence of that equivalence in online dictionaries. Maybe you can offer me some links or extra information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speakers do say things like that.

> Day-glo colors are fast-drying paints frequently used for brushing or spraying on walls, bridges, and subway-cars.

The gerunds **cutting** and **scratching** refer to specific modes of applying glyphs to a surface, analogous to **brushing or spraying**.

> Runes were old letters originally used for cutting or scratching on wood, stone, or metal...

I think the dissonance you sense stems from the fact that the *ing*-form is being used nominally and refers to a mode of application of glyphs to a surface. I imagine you'd have no problem with the following, where it is used transitively as a participle:

> Day-glo colors are fast-drying paints frequently used for brushing or spraying **graffiti** on walls, bridges, and subway-cars.
>
> Runes were old letters originally used for cutting or scratching **words and names** on wood, stone, or metal...

Comment: I get what you mean, you have employed good examples. But if you don't know what a rune is, there is no way of differentiate it from a knife in: a knife were used for cutting / a rune were used for cutting, isn't it?

Comment: True, *Runes were used for cutting on wood* would make you think a rune was a cutting implement of some kind.  But it doesn't say that. It says *Runes were **letters** for...*

Answer (score 1):

You are right to question the language, and your updated version is almost correct.

If it were my place to correct it, I would change it to the following:

> Runes were old letters that originally used **to be cut** or scratched **into** wood, stone, etc.

Or just:

> Runes were old letters originally **cut or scratched into** wood, stone, etc.

Comment: I was not sure about the past tense of "to cut". Thanks for pointing that and the right preposition.